# Prepend ## to every line in a text file

Tags: text-processing

I want to add hashes to all the lines in a regular text file. I'm fine with both the use of terminal and GUI—I just need to get it done.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sed) to do that:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^/##/' file
```

This replaces the start of the line (`^`) with `##`.

With the `-i.bak` switch, `sed` edits the file in-place, but creates a backup copy with extension`.bak`.

Comment: +1 This is the first time I encounter this backup method. I always did an inline replace directly: `sed 's/^/##/' -i file`. In this case, this would be preferred since it cannot go wrong. In other cases, this command can be combined with `diff -u file.bak file` to see the differences (if necessary, pipe it through `less`). If it's confirmed to work, the backup can be removed. Otherwise it could be restored with a simple `mv file.bak file`.

Comment: Elegant. I was thinking about something like `sed 's/^\(.*\)$/##\1/'`, but this is much nicer.

Comment: Nice one.. I was thinking about suggesting Vim to do this...

Comment: This helped me convert a block list file :) Thank you 1+

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution to this problem using perl

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {print "##$_"}' < infile > outfile
```

Comment: The `-p` switch is also useful: `perl -pe 's/^/##/' infile > outfile`. (There's also the `-i[extension]` switch for replacing the target file in-place.) http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-p%2a

Answer (score 7):

While we are at it:

```
gawk -i inplace '{print "##"$0}' infile
```

This uses the (comparatively new) [inplace editing plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/2072269) for GNU awk 4.1.0+.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) way:

```bash
while read -r; do printf '##%s\n' "$REPLY"; done < infile > outfile
```

([In the `bash` shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins), running `read -r` with no other arguments works like `IFS= read -r REPLY`.)

This is stylistically inspired by [beav_35's perl solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/55181/22949), which I admit probably runs much faster for huge files, since [`perl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/perl.1.html) may be expected to be more efficient than a shell when it comes to text processing.

Answer (score 4):

`sed -i` is not POSIX-standard, so if you are a purist you will want to use `ed`:

```
printf ",s/^/##/\nw\nq" | ed -s file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier `perl` way than presented elsewhere:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "##"' YOURFILEHERE
```

This (ab)uses the fact that `perl -p` prints the line after executing the command given in `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/^/##/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with python's mapping function and redirecting stdin:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
lorem ipsum
quick brown fox
hello world
$ python -c 'import sys;print "".join(map(lambda x: "##"+x,sys.stdin.readlines()))'  < input.txt                         
##lorem ipsum
##quick brown fox
##hello world
```

Save the output to new file and use it instead of original