# How can I find & replace first phrase, in multiple files containing the phrase multiple times?

Tags: text-processing

I want to change the first background-color following the

```
body {
```

style from whatever it is to

```
background-color: #000000;
```

in seven different stylesheets.css files via command-line. Also each .css file contains more than 10 instances, which is why I want to only change the one following the `body {` style code.

Answer (score 2):

Do some change according to your file:

```
sed  '0,/body{background-color:.*;/s//body{background-color:#000000;/' sample.css
```

or do it quickly:

```
sed  '0,/body{background-color:.*;/s//body{background-color:#000000;/' *.css
```

---

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/\a/;$!ba;s/body[ \t\a]*{[ \t\a]*background-color:#[0-9a-zA-Z]*;/body\n{background-color:#000000;/;s/\a/\n/g;' *.css
```

Source:[The sed FAQ](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html)

Comment: Might fail if there is any text (or even newlines) between `body{` and `background-color`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need a good regular expression matching your needs. `sed` is a good tool to use, `perl` is another. Only reason I'm preferring `perl` is that I know its regular expression syntax better. The following line should do what you want:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's/(body {.*?background-color.*?)#.{6}/$1#000000/si;' ./style.css
```

`-0777` means split on nothing, so slurp in whole file (instead of line by line, the default for -p)

`-i.bak` means alter files in place, leaving original with extension .bak (default for -p is to just print)

`-p` means pass line by line (except we are slurping) to passed code (see -e)

`-e` expects code to run.

Explaining the regular expression is beyond the scope of my answer, but there are many tutorials out there like [this one](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm) for example.

Be sure to check the results as I can easily imagine css files which would cause problems with this expression. For example having selectors which contain the word body might cause problems...

Answer (score 1):

I would try for `awk`:

```
gawk -v RS='}[[:space:]]*' '/^body[[:space:]]*{/ { 
  printf "%s%s", gensub (/background-color:[^;]*;/, "background-color: #000000;", 1), RT
}'
```

This requires GNU awk (but can be done without it as well).

- We set the record separator to `}` followed by any amount of whitespace.
- Then we can match `body {` to the beginning of the record.
- And substitute `background-color: #000000;` for the first instance of `background-color`. Replace `1` with `g` to match all instances.
- `RT` contains the text matched by the record separator. If we used a fixed string (`}`) instead of a regular expression, we could use `ORS` instead. `RT` needs GNU awk.
- GNU awk also has an [in-place editing plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55089/prepend-to-every-line-in-a-text-file/525395#525395). Use `gawk -i inplace ...`

Truly speaking, this is not a job for regular expressions or record parsers. Something that understands the CSS language should be used.